# Microsoft Azure PostgreSQL Event Trigger vs. SuperUser

Tags: postgresql, azure, events, triggers

I am using [Microsoft Azure Database for PostgreSQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/postgresql/) with PostgreSQL 10 installed. As I'm trying to work on future tables together with other users I want to enable the other users to alter my tables as well.

I've created a role pgpublish and all users are members of the role. For a new table, which I created, I altered the table owner to the role *pgpublish*. Now everyone with the role *pgpublish* is able to alter the table:

```
ALTER TABLE "MYcoolSchema"."CoolNewTable" OWNER TO pgpublish;
```

To make this more automatic/generic, I created a trigger function and tried to create an event trigger [as explained here](https://blog.hagander.net/setting-owner-at-create-table-237/).

Unfortunately I can't create the event trigger (The trigger function works fine), as it is stated:

```
ERROR: permission denied to create event trigger
"trg_create_set_owner" HINT: Must be superuser to create an event trigger. 
SQL state: 42501
```

Is there a workaround for creating event triggers on Microsoft Azure Database for PostgreSQL? How can this look like?

I could run a cron job on another system to scan for new tables and alter the owner of these new tables to pgpublish but this is not cool at all.

Comment: Hi Riccardo - Please make an entry to request the desired functionality on this forum: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/597976-azure-database-for-PostgreSQL I am working with the product group to get you an interim solution.

Comment: @MikeUbezziMSFT: been there, done that: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/597976-azure-database-for-postgresql/suggestions/36435115-allow-event-triggers-to-be-created

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I have an email into the product group requesting work around or solution to your issue. Super User access will eventually arrive but not without building use cases. Thanks again.

Comment: So, Azure Database for PostgreSQL is offered as PaaS, and there is currently a permissions limitation with this offering. There is no short-term solution and the product team has viewed your User Voice request. That being said, you could deploy PostgreSQL on an Ubuntu VM (available through Azure Marketplace as PostgreSQL 9.5 on Ubuntu). This will give you complete control of your instance but there is more involved to set-up and at (most likely) additional costs but, you get to what you are looking for.